# Sudoku-solving program

Tags: c++, time-limit-exceeded, sudoku, backtracking

This is a Sudoku solver program which uses backtracking. It is a problem from *Online Judge* and I made it work after some struggle, but it needs to be faster as I'm getting a *Time Limit Exceeded* message.

The input format:

```
.46...9..
.3.1.....
.2..6..85
...87....
6...3...4
....14...
79..5..3.
.....2.4.
..2...61.
```

And then I just need to output the solved board. I am probably making some repeated calls, unnecessary calculations/comparisons that make the program slower, but I don't have any clue how to make this faster.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
int already_given[9+1][9+1];
bool used_list_for_row[9+1][9+1] ; //[current row][current value]
bool used_list_for_col[9+1][9+1] ; //[current col][current value]
bool used_list_for_box[9+1][9+1] ; //[current box][current value]
int solution[9+1][9+1];
inline void init()
{
    for(int x=1;x<=9;x++)
        for(int y=1;y<=9;y++)
    {
        already_given[x][y] = 0;
        used_list_for_box[x][y] = false;
        used_list_for_col[x][y] = false;
        used_list_for_row[x][y] = false;

    }
}
inline void print_solution()
{
    for(int r=1;r<=9;r++)
    {for(int c=1;c<=9;c++)
    {
        if(!already_given[r][c])
        printf("%d",solution[r][c]);
        else
            printf("%d",already_given[r][c]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    }

}
inline int from_r_c_ret_box(int r,int c)
{
    if(c>=1 && c<=3)
    {
        if(r>=1 && r<=3) return 1;
    if(r>=3 && r<=6) return 4;
        if(r>=6 && r<=9) return 7;

    }
    if(c>=3 && c<=6)
    {
        if(r>=1 && r<=3) return 2;
    if(r>=3 && r<=6) return 5;
        if(r>=6 && r<=9) return 8;

    }
    if(c>=6 && c<=9)
    {
        if(r>=1 && r<=3) return 3;
    if(r>=3 && r<=6) return 6;
        if(r>=6 && r<=9) return 9;

    }
}

inline void solver(int cur_row,int cur_col)
{
    int cur_box = from_r_c_ret_box(cur_row,cur_col);
    if(!already_given[cur_row][cur_col])
    for(int possible_val = 1;possible_val<=9;possible_val++)
    {if(!used_list_for_row[cur_row][possible_val])
        if(!used_list_for_col[cur_col][possible_val])
        if(!used_list_for_box[cur_box][possible_val])
    {
        solution[cur_row][cur_col] = possible_val;
    used_list_for_row[cur_row][possible_val] = true;
    used_list_for_col[cur_col][possible_val] = true;
    used_list_for_box[cur_box][possible_val] = true;

    if(cur_col==9 && cur_row == 9)
    {
        print_solution();
    }
    if(cur_col==9 && cur_row!=9)
        solver(cur_row+1,1);
else
        solver(cur_row,cur_col+1);

  //      printf("R:%d  C:%d  V:%d\n",cur_row,cur_col,possible_val);

    used_list_for_row[cur_row][possible_val] = false;
    used_list_for_col[cur_col][possible_val] = false;
    used_list_for_box[cur_box][possible_val] = false;


    }

    }

    if(already_given[cur_row][cur_col])
    {
         if(cur_col==9 && cur_row == 9)
    {
        print_solution();
    }
    if(cur_col==9 && cur_row!=9)
        solver(cur_row+1,1);
else
        solver(cur_row,cur_col+1);

    }
}
inline int ctoi(char c)
{
    return (c-'0');
}
void process(char ch,int r,int c)
{
    if(ch<='9' && ch>='1')
{
    already_given[r][c] = ctoi(ch);
used_list_for_row[r][ctoi(ch)] = true;
used_list_for_col[c][ctoi(ch)] = true;
used_list_for_box[from_r_c_ret_box(r,c)][ctoi(ch)] = true;


}
}
int main()
{

int tc = 0;
scanf("%d",&tc);
for(int testcase=1;testcase<=tc;testcase++)
{
    init();
    char c;int counter_row = 1,counter_col = 0;
    while(1)
    {
        c = getchar();
        if(counter_row*counter_col==81) break;
        if(c=='.' || (c<='9' && c>='1')  )
        {
            if(counter_row==9 && counter_col==9)
                {
 process(c,counter_row,counter_col);

                    break;}
            else if(counter_col==9 && counter_row!=9)
            {
                counter_row++;counter_col=1;
            }
            else
            {
                counter_col++;counter_row=counter_row;
            }
            process(c,counter_row,counter_col);

        }
    }
    printf("Case %d:\n",testcase);

solver(1,1);
//printf("\n");
}



    return 0;
}
```

I have been coding this for last 6 hours without any help (just from the concept of backtracking and I'm also bad at recursion). There are some similar questions but I want to specifically know what I can do with my code to make it faster.

Comment: [Cross-posted from Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31508425/1157100)

Comment: I was told to post it in the codereview section

Comment: No problem with cross-posting. Just declare it properly so that you don't waste other users' time.

Comment: Please for the love of all that is holy, fix your indentation. Spend two minutes clicking around on here, learn how people usually indent C++ code, and copy their style. Once that's fixed, we can talk about the subtler problems with the code.

Answer (score 1):

- The indentation is a complete mess. I have seriously never seen this before
- You are reinventing the wheel with *ctoi*, which, if I understood well, does basically what [atoi](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/) does.
- There isn't a single **useful** comment in your code. It's either dead code (which should be removed) or some strange thing
- The naming of your variables is quite bad and inconsistent. One example  : *x*, *y*, *r* and *c*. I guess *x* and *r* are the same thing and that the same goes for *y* and *c*. *x* and *y* are maybe the only one-character long variable names that are acceptable (and I personally prefer *iRow* and *iCol* to avoid confusion), but that's just one example.
- `if(ch<='9' && ch>='1')` You're just lucky that works. If you want to use comparison, prefer using numbers, not characters that are represented by numbers by the machine.
- Multiple expressions on one line (`counter_row++;counter_col=1;` for example) is also something you don't quite see often. The main reason is that it does not make you win anything but a line in your file (and who cares ?), but it makes your code hard to read.
- The types of your variables is also quite bad. Let's look at that `int from_r_c_ret_box(int r,int c)`. We've kind of figured that *r* and *c* are *rows* and *columns* numbers, so why do you allow them to take negative values ? *unsigned int* would be better, and as a sudoku is a 9*9 square, *unsigned short* would be perfect.
- the `while(1)` is useless and dangerous. Just make a proper condition, or even better, as you know the number of iteration, do a for loop (well, two in this case).

That's already quite a lot to do before even considering improving the algorithm. Bit it would be a pleasure to make another review once you have corrected the few points below (if you want to do that, post another question, don't edit this one).

Comment: Some of this is bad advice; for example, the advice to replace `int` with `unsigned short` throughout your code. Also notice that `'1'<=ch && ch<='9'` *is* guaranteed to do the right thing in C and C++, no matter what the execution character set is; the digits `'0'` through `'9'` *must* be contiguous and in order, even if the implementation has to jump through hoops to make that happen on your platform.

Comment: Can you explain why using `unsigned short` type for columns and rows ranging from 0 to 8 (or 1 to 9) is bad advice ? I get the validity of the other point (but since he converts the characters to integers just after, I would defintely convert first and check the result after conversion), but not this one.